# Installing NS2 2.35 on mac OS El Capitan Error Building xgraph -lSM library not found

Tags: macos, ns2

I'm trying to install NS2 2.35 on mac OS El Capitan
I have this error showing up when I run ./install64

I don't understand why it shows that and I don't know where to find lSM

> ============================================================
>   * Build XGraph-12.2
>   ============================================================ configure: error: expected an absolute directory name for --prefix: ..
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make  all-am
>
> gcc     -g      -o xgraph xgraph.o xgX.o hard_devices.o dialog.o
>   hpgl.o ps.o idraw.o xtb.o st.o params.o alloc.o draw.o init.o read.o
>   tgif.o derivative.o   -lSM -lICE  -lX11 -lm
>
> ld: library not found for -lSM
>
> clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see
>   invocation)
>
> make[1]: *** [xgraph] Error 1
>
> make: *** [all] Error 2
>
> Can not create xgraph; But xgraph is an optional package,
>   continuing...

Answer (score 0):

---

> ld: library not found for -lSM

`-lSM` means `libSM.so` . From the X.Org X11 libSM library.

So please install libSM / libsm , if available. If you already have the runtime library `libSM.so.6 > libSM.so.6.0.1` , a symlink will do : `# ln -s libSM.so.6.0.1 libSM.so` , as xgraph is not requiring any of the header files : SM.h, SMlib.h, SMproto.h .

Note : xgraph is an optional package, will be skipped if the build fails.

Note 2 : `libSM.so` is not required for ns-2.35 or any other applications in ns-allinone-2.35 .

---

---